# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException trying to access data

Tags: java

I am getting an array index out of bounds exception in the following code:

```
for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {
    int a[][] = new int[10][3];
double LeftTrim = 1.0;
double RightTrim = 1.0;

a [i][0]=(int) (LeftTrim*((i)*25));
a [i][1]=(int) (RightTrim*((i)*25));
a [i][2]= 5000;

//leftWheel, rightWheel, Milliseconds
myf.setWheelVelocities(a[i][0], a[i][1], a[i][2]);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, + (a [i][0]  +  a [i][1])/2 + "wheel velocities"  + " | " + a [i][2] + " Milliseconds" +  " Click OK to continue...");
}
```

Every-time I reach the 9th increment Eclipse gives me the error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10"
```

I have to test the velocity up to 250, but when I reach 225 and I click 'Ok' on 'Click ok to continue..." this error shows up! Am I going out of the array bounds or something?

EDIT: The speed velocity has to start from 25, 50, 75 ... 250 (so ten in all)

Thank you!

Comment: Size 10, goes from 0 to 9. There's no [10]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The valid values of `i` in `a[i]` are `0` to `9`. Your code iterates to `10`.

Also, the loop starts from `1` whereas it *might* need to start from `0`.

Finally, the fact that you're allocating the 2D array inside the loop look pretty odd. Either move it outside the loop, or turn it into a three-element 1D array.

Comment: Hi sorry, we have to start the velocity from 25 (first speed). So I would presume the loop should start from 1. The next problem is that  I can't get it to test the speed 250. I can do up to 225, but when I press "ok" on the 250 speed, program ends? I've changed it to for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {
    int a[][] = new int[11][3];  Any help please? Oh and the velocity speed can't get any higher than 250.

Comment: This is the correct answer. A 10-sized goes from 0 to 9, so the usual pattern is of the form `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`. If you want to start with velocity at 25, you'll either have to start from `i = 0` and calculate using `(i + 1)*25` (better idea) or start from `i = 1` and access the array using `[i - 1]` (less good idea).

Comment: WOOOOOOO, IT WORKED. THANK YOU AND I APOLOGIZE FOR SHOUTING.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your code to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
}
```

In Java, array indexes starts at `0`.